# UIFont crash problem

Tags: iphone

When i use this line

```
  [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:16]  its work fine,but

   [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial Black" size:16]  it crashes my app.....
```

In xib design there is the font name of Arial Black is available.But when i set using [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial Black" size:16] this it crashes my app.. How can i set this font name to uilabel...

Can any one help me?

Answer (score 2):

Check the return value of +[UIFont fontWithName:size:]. My guess is that "Arial Black" is not being found, and a nil font is being returned. Setting a UILabel's font to nil will crash.

Answer (score 1):

To add - using `+familyNames` and `+fontNamesForFamilyName` methods in UIFont you can list all fonts available.

Answer (score 1):

You need `Arial-BoldMT`

```
[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:16];
```

See [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1533499?start=0&tstart=0)